# How to avoid repetition on data insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, repeat

I wish to allow all application users to add their own categories for their products. The produts may vary A LOT so is not just something that I can predict and insert myself previously.

However, if we allow all users to add their own categories, we may have issues like:

User A inserts a category called: Fruits

User B inserts a category called: Food from trees

(this is a dummy example, but perhaps you get the problem).

Generally speaking, what ways to we have to avoid repetition on our system ?

I'm totally unaware of the ways we may have, so some resources, links, anything, are more then welcome.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not the most friendly solution, but you could add all new entries to a queue that is moderated by a select number of users. Only after approval, the new entries will appear.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that we need to find an automated way of doing it, since we will not have the resources to deal with that.

Comment: @MEM an automated solution to avoid `food from trees` when `fruits` exists?! You probably need less time moderating than writing that algoritm :-)

Comment: @MEM: Your example would require the IBM Watson machine to reason linguistically about the potential overlaps in meaning between "Fruits" and "Food from trees".  Even Professional human Philosophers working on Ontologies would have a hard time sorting your example out.  Indeed, as a native speaker of English, I can't figure out wether they are the same or different.

Comment: @S.Lott @jeroen - ok... I believe a semantic interpreation should be in place here, and true, I don't have the knowledge nor the resources to make that happen. What about some workaround: I mean, here on stackoverflow, we have a LOT of tags, and we don't have repetition... Well... but we don't have an implicit hierarchy either... hmm.:)

Comment: @MEM But we do have a looooooooooot of moderators :)

Comment: @MEM: "we don't have repetition".  I'll assume you're kidding about that.  Explain the difference (if possible) between [Unit Testing] and [TDD].  Overlap in meaning?  No overlap?  And how would you tell? What test would you -- as a human -- use to determine if they're duplicates?

Comment: @MEM but the difference is in the approach, I guess here you can add a tag if you have enough rep and you can start using it without it being moderated first. I guess it gets merged with other existing tags if it gets moderated after you add and start using it and it is found to be a duplicate.

Comment: @jeroen @S.Lott - Indeed. And, not ALL users can just start introducing tags... they must have certain privileges. I can for example allow the users to introduce some categories and if those categories are requested by N number of users, they get implemented. However, those categories related to very specific products will not have so many users working with them, as we get nothing from there... arrgh!

Comment: @MEM It also depends how general / open your system is, perhaps a solution would be to give all users their own categories and limit them to their own ones only. After all in the end the number of categories will only be a fraction of the number of products.

Comment: @jeroen: Indeed. Percentage and relativism could play a role here. Well, the main point of my question is not, of course, to start a brain storm, even if I really need one now ;), but it was to see if there where any common solution for this situation that I was not aware off, and, I believe there isn't any out-of-the-box one. I'm also very critic to "pseudo artificial intelligence" and I do by principle agree that semantic interpretation is indeed something we human can do really well and it's more then linguistic issues we are talking here. H. Dreyfus has a point here. :)

Answer (score 2):

If is how i understand:

First, recomended categories name, if the user start type "fru", display an exists caregories callesd "fruits" and etc.

I use aliases, example:

Table Categories:

```
id (serial)
name (varchar)
aliasof (bigint)
```

From a backend i listing a new categories added, and if exists, make a relation:

Supose:

```
1 fruits         0
2 fruits of tree 1
```

Comment: Thanks. The users unfortunately are not technical aware and normally they will just insert no matter what EVEN IF, we present them some alternatives and we warning them, "please avoid introducing new data if you have here a similar one listed". That is the challenge here in fact. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hierarchical categories, so that when this situation is encountered it can be handled cleanly. Then when someone comes along and removes the child category the elements can be dumped into the parent category.

Comment: Care to explain a little bit more. The main reason why we need to avoid this is to: a) allow comparison (later on) b) avoid database garbage.